# Русский вариант метки language-design

Tags: обсуждение, метки

Попался вопрос [Почему имена встроенных функций в Go набраны строчными буквами?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/457434/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-go-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)

Хотел добавить ему соответствующую метку, но что-то у нас её пока нет.
Да и перевести у меня красиво что-то не получается...

[language-design на английском SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-design)

Comment: велосипедостроение

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, ему иногда очень хочется найти место в другой ситуации.

Comment: Вот тоже [вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413793/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%A2%D0%97-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%8F%D0%B7%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F), пожалуй, подходящий под эту метку

Answer (score 6):

[language-design](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-design) - сделать метку с английским названием.

Хм.. Пожалуй, это в любом случае имеет смысл, а там её синонимом сделаем.

Answer (score 3):

[дизайн-языков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2) - не уверен, насколько понятно, но этот вариант мне нравится больше других.

Comment: Возможно, стоит использовать единственное число?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, возможно... Даже и не знаю.

Answer (score 3):

[теория-языков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2) - от англоязычного названия дисциплины [Programming Language Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language_theory).

Comment: Но мы же всё-таки о практике говорим. Мне по этой же причине "проектирование языков" не нравится.

Comment: Самый оптимальный вариант из всех

Answer (score 3):

Я бы предложил ещё [устройство-языков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2)

Comment: Прекрасно отражает суть.

Answer (score 3):

ABBYY Lingvo, вариант 2:
*конструкция языка* [программирования] здесь речь идёт не об отдельной языковой конструкции, а о внутреннем устройстве (организации) языка в целом

Comment: За «конструкцию языка», только хорошо бы иметь два разных варианта в разных сообщениях.

Comment: как насчет множественного числа?

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну судя по описанию это понятие не подразумевает множественного числа, так как оно имманентно языку

Answer (score 0):

[дизайн-языков-программирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f) - длинновато.

Comment: Превышает 25 символов, нельзя.

Comment: @NickVolynkin надеюсь, это ограничение преодолимо. Иначе довольно грустно. Довольно много полезных меток не подойдёт под такую длину, а короче они будут плохо смотреться

Answer (score 0):

[проектирование-языков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2) - красиво, но скорее отражает процесс, чем результат.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть, подойдёт [анатомия-языков](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2).

Comment: звучит интересно, но новоиспеченный участник, задающий вопрос еще должен о ней догадаться.

Comment: @Nofate: создать синоним: language-design -> анатомия-языков (и соответственно для других вероятных вариантов).

Answer (score 0):

Ещё вариант: [как-устроены-языки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8).

Answer (score 0):

ABBYY Lingvo, вариант 1:
*конструирование языка* [программирования]

Answer (score -1):

[языки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%8f%d0%b7%d1%8b%d0%ba%d0%b8) - единственный плюс, что метка уже существует

Comment: Это мета-метка: [Выдрать язык](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/287)

Comment: @Nofate, там часть значений надо исключить, а остальные в целом где-то в близкой тематике.